# UnitOfWork in Action Filter seems to be caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, inversion-of-control, unit-of-work, action-filter

I have an MVC 3 site that uses IoC (Unity), and my model is generated w/ EF4 and POCOs. I am using an action filter to commit my UnitOfWork:

```
public class UseUnitOfWorkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public UseUnitOfWorkAttribute()
    {
        _unitOfWork = IoCFactory.Instance.CurrentContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
    }

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

However, even though the `Commit()` seems to be getting fired, it somehow seems to be caching what it thinks is "dirty".

For example, in my controller, the following gets executed from a service class:

```
var user = _userRepository.Single(u => u.Id == 2);
user.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
```

Whenever I do a fresh build of the solution and hit this controller action, the change is actually committed.  However, successive hits to the controller doesn't do anything.

On the other hand, if I put a UnitOfWork in my controller and commit it following the service method call, it works as expected (every time I request the controller action):

```
public AccountController()
{
    _unitOfWork = IoCFactory.Instance.CurrentContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
}

public ActionResult Test()
{
    var user = _userRepository.Single(u => u.Id == 2);
    user.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
    _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

So it definitely seems like some sort of caching is going on, but I can't figure it out what is getting cached -- the UnitOfWork, the ActionFilter, or the repository.

Any ideas what could be going on?  And if not, any ideas what else I could do to troubleshoot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are initializing your unit of work in the constructor of the action filter which means that it will be injected when the action filter is instantiated. Quote from the [ASP.NET MVC 3 release notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#RTM-BC):

> In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC,
>   action filters were created per
>   request except in a few cases. This
>   behavior was never a guaranteed
>   behavior but merely an implementation
>   detail and the contract for filters
>   was to consider them stateless. In
>   ASP.NET MVC 3, filters are cached more
>   aggressively. Therefore, any custom
>   action filters which improperly store
>   instance state might be broken.

Comment: Thank you, this is excatly what's going on.  I tried finding information regarding action filter caching, but never came across this in my searches.

Comment: I wish I could up vote this 5x. Killer when upgrading MVC 1/2 applications.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the dependency container returns the same instance in all places and rewrite the filter to avoid state caching:

```
public class UseUnitOfWorkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var unitOfWork = IoCFactory.Instance.CurrentContainer.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
        unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the lifetime on your repository. That was certainly the culprit in our implementation.

Comment: I am using `TransientLifetimeManager()` on my repositories.  My ObjectContext and UnitOfWork are both using a custom `PerExecutionContextLifetimeManager()`, which is basically per-request lifetime.  Should my repositories also be `PerExecutionContextLifetimeManager()`?

Comment: Update: I just tried that, just to rule that out, and using `PerExecutionContextLifetimeManager()` also seems to have the same results.  Are there other options I should try?