# How to prevent MVC ActionFilterAttribute from being cached?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC API ActionFilterAttribute that does a permissions check using the Entity Framework.  I've found that because of ActionFilterAttribute caching the EF connection is often broken.  You can find other questions about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335350/unitofwork-in-action-filter-seems-to-be-caching). So does anyone know how to prevent caching in ActionFilterAttributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Just a Note to your title*: I would say that Action Filters in MVC are not cached, they act as singletons (as explained in the link you've provided).

As the answer to your needs I would say use Request based persistence. Because you would most likely want to do some stuff like:
- OnActionExecuting() (e.g. open Transaction)
- OnActionExecuted() (commit or rollback)

So put your object (_unitOfWork) into

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items
```

You can access it form the singleton methods, while operating on request dependent objects. I am doing it similar way with NHibernate Session