# Do FilterAttributes Get Cached In ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

I have an issue with HTTPS and HTTP.  It seems my filterattribute is being cached.  When I login, it should automatically send none http pages to https, which it does.  Then when I logout it stays on https which is fine, but if I try to manually go to a non http page, it redirects to a https page again even though I am logged in.  The RequireSecure is always true because my logging info says it is.  Do FilterAttributes get cached and if so how can I fix this?

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute
    {
        protected static readonly NLogLogger Logger = new NLogLogger();

        public bool Ignore = false;
        public bool RequireSecure = false;

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Logger.Info("Require HTTPS User Authenticated");

                RequireSecure = true;
            }

            if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
                RequireSecure = false;

            if (RequireSecure)
            {
                Logger.Info("Require HTTPS");

                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is correct behavior. The details could be found here:

- [UnitOfWork in Action Filter seems to be caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335350/#5335953).
- http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#RTM-BC

A short extract:

> *...In ASP.NET MVC 3, filters are cached more aggressively. Therefore, any custom action filters which improperly store instance state might be broken.*

I would suggest to store data important for a `filter attribute` to: Request scope

> filterContext.HttpContext.Items

And as a Session Scope (like in your case):

> filterContext.HttpContext.Session
>
> filterContext.HttpContext.Profile

Comment: Well the problem is it never gets hit again, so I cant even compare anything.